# Why does resizing of JTable column generate garbage?

Tags: java, swing, garbage-collection, jtable

I'm currently implementing a program that uses a JTable to display some information. The table contains no more than 10 rows (so it's small).

While developing, I usually run the programs with the `-verbose:gc` option.

If I click on the line between 2 columns and keep moving it to the left, then to the right and so on, I notice that a lot of garbage is generated. **The program does absolutely nothing while I'm doing this**, so there is no other potential source of this garbage. Also, If I stop, the garbage collector also stops collecting.

If I keep resizing these columns for a minute or so, about **100MB+ of garbage** is generated, which seems a lot.

This is not affecting how my program runs, but it just seems very weird. Why does it behave this way ?

**EDIT**

Here is an SSCCE:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class JTableTest
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater (new Runnable ()
        {
            @Override public void run ()
            {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame ();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout (null);
                frame.setSize (700, 300);
                frame.setResizable (false);

                JTable table = new JTable ();
                table.setAutoResizeMode (JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);

                String[] titles = { "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4", "Title 5" };

                String[][] data = {
                                { "Row 1, Column 1", "Row 1, Column 2", "Row 1, Column 3", "Row 1, Column 4", "Row 1, Column 5"},
                                { "Row 2, Column 1", "Row 2, Column 2", "Row 2, Column 3", "Row 2, Column 4", "Row 2, Column 5"},
                                { "Row 3, Column 1", "Row 3, Column 2", "Row 3, Column 3", "Row 3, Column 4", "Row 3, Column 5"},
                                { "Row 4, Column 1", "Row 4, Column 2", "Row 4, Column 3", "Row 4, Column 4", "Row 4, Column 5"},
                                { "Row 5, Column 1", "Row 5, Column 2", "Row 5, Column 3", "Row 5, Column 4", "Row 5, Column 5"}
                                };

                table.setModel (new DefaultTableModel (data, titles)
                {
                    @Override public boolean isCellEditable (int row, int column)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                });

                JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane (table);
                scrollpane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy (ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
                scrollpane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy (ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

                scrollpane.setBounds (20, 20, 650, 250);
                frame.add (scrollpane);

                frame.setVisible (true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Run the program with the `-verbose:gc` option. When running, click between "Title x" and "Title y" (x != y) and resize those columns. Keep the mouse clicked and keep moving it left and right. You'll see on `stdout` that the garbage collector is collecting garbage while you do this. (on my system it's doing this about 10 times / minute). **If/when you stop, no more garbage is collected.**

Comment: better would be edit your question with a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) with rellated Renderers, because I think that every answers here will be shots to the dark

Comment: *"I usually run the programs with the `-verbose:gc` option."*  I would advise switching that off until you hit an `OutOfMemroyError` or see performance lags.  "Don't stress the minor details."

Comment: @mKorbel I have updated my question with an SSCCE.

Comment: I'll elaborate and check with JProfiler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It generates garbage simply because it can. Java is a Garbage Collected language, essentially everything it does creates garbage.

While you are holding down and dragging that button, java is taking primitive activity (i.e. mouse button status, cursor position status, time, etc.) and creating events. It then compares that stream of events to things like old cursor position etc. to detect if the program actually wants to do anything with that information. When you do move it, Java needs to draw lines, file rectangles, draw text, etc.

All of those activity leave behind something, garbage, and eventually it needs to be collected.

Just sitting idle, your program is creating garbage, most likely very slowly, as internal timers and such die and are recycled. Try using the jconsole program to watch the heap and you'll see it creep up over time.

This is normal, and nothing to worry about. It's a feature, not a bug.

Comment: It does make sense what you say and it seems that it is the case here. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

please

- some changes in code
- added JTextArea
- do you confirm us that your output is the same as the output printed into JTextArea

(WinXP, Java6 --> looks like as forever)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultCaret;

public class JTableTest {

    private javax.swing.Timer timer = null;
    private JTextArea text = new JTextArea();

    public JTableTest() {
        String[] titles = {"Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4", "Title 5"};
        String[][] data = {
            {"Row 1, Column 1", "Row 1, Column 2", "Row 1, Column 3", "Row 1, Column 4", "Row 1, Column 5"},
            {"Row 2, Column 1", "Row 2, Column 2", "Row 2, Column 3", "Row 2, Column 4", "Row 2, Column 5"},
            {"Row 3, Column 1", "Row 3, Column 2", "Row 3, Column 3", "Row 3, Column 4", "Row 3, Column 5"},
            {"Row 4, Column 1", "Row 4, Column 2", "Row 4, Column 3", "Row 4, Column 4", "Row 4, Column 5"},
            {"Row 5, Column 1", "Row 5, Column 2", "Row 5, Column 3", "Row 5, Column 4", "Row 5, Column 5"}
        };
        JTable table = new JTable();
        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
        table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(data, titles) {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);
        scrollpane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        scrollpane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);


        DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret) text.getCaret();
        caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(text);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocation(150, 150);
        frame.setSize(700, 300);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.add(scrollpane, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        start();
    }

    private void start() {
        timer = new javax.swing.Timer(1000, updateCol());
        timer.start();
    }

    public Action updateCol() {
        return new AbstractAction("text load action") {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                text.append("FreeMemory in Kb " + Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() / 1000 + "\n");
                text.append("MaxMemory in Kb " + Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1000 + "\n");
                text.append("TotalMemory in Kb " + Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() / 1000 + "\n");
                text.append("UsedMemory in Kb " + ((Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()) / 1000) + "\n");
                text.append("\n");
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JTableTest jTableTest = new JTableTest();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

EDIT JTable and GC a few columns with 75k rows (82 -85Mb)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;


public class TriState extends JPanel {

    private static final long K = 1024;
    private static final long M = K * K;
    private static final long G = M * K;
    private static final long T = G * K;
    protected static int ctr = 1;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JButton btnShow = new JButton("Show Form");
    private JLabel lblMem = new JLabel();
    private static final DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.#");
    protected Timer updateTimer = new Timer();

    public TriState() {
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        add(btnShow);
        add(lblMem);
        updateTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new UpdateTimerTask(), 1000, 1000);
        btnShow.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                FrmReferrals fr = new FrmReferrals();
                fr.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    class UpdateTimerTask extends TimerTask {

        public void run() {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    dumpMemoryUsage();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    protected void dumpMemoryUsage() {
        System.gc();
        Long t = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
        long f = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();

        String st = convertToStringRepresentation(t);
        String sf = convertToStringRepresentation(f);
        String su = convertToStringRepresentation(t - f);
        System.out.println("Total:" + st + "(" + t + ") Free:" + sf + "(" + f + ") Used:" + su + "(" + (t - f) + ")");
        lblMem.setText(su + "/" + st);

    }

    public static String convertToStringRepresentation(final long value) {
        final long[] dividers = new long[]{T, G, M, K, 1};
        final String[] units = new String[]{"TB", "GB", "MB", "KB", "B"};
        if (value < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid file size: " + value);
        }
        String result = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < dividers.length; i++) {
            final long divider = dividers[i];
            if (value >= divider) {
                final double dr = divider > 1 ? (double) value / (double) divider : (double) value;
                result = df.format(dr) + units[i];
                break;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleTableDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Create and set up the content pane.
        TriState newContentPane = new TriState();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); // content panes must be opaque
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        // Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    protected class PopupMenu extends JPopupMenu {

        public PopupMenu() {
            JRadioButtonMenuItem item1 = new JRadioButtonMenuItem(new AbstractAction("Insert Item") {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getActionCommand());
                }
            });
            item1.setActionCommand("Insert");
            add(item1);

            JRadioButtonMenuItem item2 = new JRadioButtonMenuItem(new AbstractAction("Delete Item") {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getActionCommand());
                }
            });
            item2.setActionCommand("Delete");
            add(item2);
        }
    }

    public class FrmReferrals extends JFrame {

        public FrmReferrals() {
            super();
            init();
        }

        protected void init() {
            jbInit();
        }

        protected void closeIt() {
            uninit();
        }
        // variables here
        final Dimension dimPreferred = new Dimension(1270, 995);
        final JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        private JTable tblReferrals = null;
        private PopupMenu popMenu = new PopupMenu();

        protected void jbInit() {
            setPreferredSize(dimPreferred);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            setTitle("Referrals");
            JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
            pnl.setOpaque(false);
            pnl.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            pnl.add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            // put it all in the frame
            add(pnl);
            pack();
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            // init the table and model
            ReferralsTableModel ctm = new ReferralsTableModel(buildDummyVector());
            tblReferrals = new JTable(ctm);
            tblReferrals.setComponentPopupMenu(popMenu);
            tblReferrals.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
            tabbedPane.add(new JScrollPane(tblReferrals, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED));

            addWindowListener(new WindowListener() {

                @Override
                public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
                }

                @Override
                public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
                }

                @Override
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                    closeIt();
                }

                @Override
                public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
                }

                @Override
                public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
                }

                @Override
                public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
                }

                @Override
                public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
                }
            });
        }

        protected Vector<DBO_Referrals> buildDummyVector() {
            Vector<DBO_Referrals> vr = new Vector<DBO_Referrals>();
            for (int x = 0; x < 75000; x++) {
                DBO_Referrals r = new DBO_Referrals(x + (5000 * ctr));
                vr.add(r);
            }
            return vr;
        }

        protected void uninit() {
            tblReferrals.setComponentPopupMenu(null);
            for (Component c : popMenu.getComponents()) {
                PropertyChangeListener[] pl = c.getPropertyChangeListeners();
                for (PropertyChangeListener l : pl) {
                    c.removePropertyChangeListener(l);
                }
                if (c instanceof JMenuItem) {
                    ActionListener[] al = ((JMenuItem) c).getActionListeners();
                    for (ActionListener l : al) {
                        ((JMenuItem) c).removeActionListener(l);
                    }
                }
            }
            popMenu = null;
        }

        protected class DBO_Referrals {

            private long id;
            private String Employee;
            private String Rep;
            private String Asst;
            private String Client;
            private String Dates;
            private String Status;
            private String Home;

            public DBO_Referrals(long id) {
                this.id = id;
                Employee = "Employee" + id;
                Rep = "Rep" + id;
                Asst = "Asst" + id;
                Client = "Client" + id;
                Dates = "Dates" + id;
                Status = "Status" + id;
                Home = "Home" + id;
            }

            public long getId() {
                return id;
            }

            public String getEmployee() {
                return Employee;
            }

            public String getRep() {
                return Rep;
            }

            public String getAsst() {
                return Asst;
            }

            public String getClient() {
                return Client;
            }

            public String getDates() {
                return Dates;
            }

            public String getStatus() {
                return Status;
            }

            public String getHome() {
                return Home;
            }
        }

        public class ReferralsTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            private Vector<DBO_Referrals> data = new Vector<DBO_Referrals>();
            final String[] sColumns = {"id", "Employee", "Rep", "Assistant", "Client", "Date", "Status", "Home", "R"};

            public ReferralsTableModel() {
                super();
            }

            public ReferralsTableModel(Vector<DBO_Referrals> data) {
                this();
                this.data = data;
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int col) {
                switch (col) {
                    case 0:
                        return Long.class;
                    default:
                        return String.class;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public int getColumnCount() {
                return sColumns.length;
            }

            @Override
            public int getRowCount() {
                return data.size();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
                if (row > data.size()) {
                    return null;
                }
                DBO_Referrals a = data.get(row);
                switch (col) {
                    case 0:
                        return a.getId();
                    case 1:
                        return a.getEmployee();
                    case 2:
                        return a.getRep();
                    case 3:
                        return a.getAsst();
                    case 4:
                        return a.getClient();
                    case 5:
                        return a.getDates();
                    case 6:
                        return a.getStatus();
                    case 7:
                        return a.getHome();
                    case 8:
                        return "+";
                    default:
                        return null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Functions as expected on Mac OS X.

Comment: but I'm quite sure that this question was about something different, then my answer went about asking the question:-)

Comment: Your example corrects the original's [Initial Threads](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html), which mitigates the GC mentioned by @Will. I had to use the profiler to see it.

Comment: hehehe JProfiler returns me similair value, only Custom Renderer can raising 100Mb :-) and not for simple JTable with 10row, maybe we can talikng abou 15-30_columns * 5000_rows

Comment: OP may have single-core processor or virtual machine.

Comment: I'll edit rellated code for testing GC & JTable, please see my edit there, there isn't value from Graphics/2D somehow important (Graphics came only from visible JViewport if I undestand..)